# CLion highlight settings (override)

Tags: ide, overriding, settings, highlight, clion

I'm using CLion IDE, and I really enjoy it, but one thing is quite annoying and I can't get rid of it.
CLion highlights every function declaration that overrides another function in base class with "Annotate this function with override or (rarely) final". As far as I know override keyword is an optional keyword. I would use it, but I recently joined this big sized project and I want to stay consistent to its conventions - and they don't use override keyword.
But the problem is that I couldn't find anywhere in CLion's settings where to disable this highlight option (I've tried using search option in settings, but still nothing).
It is a bit annoying because it highlights most of functions in my derived classes, and I have to mouse over it to check if it is an important notice, or just this "Annotate this...".

Comment: Have you tried looking under the inspection settings of CLion? Try > Editor > Inspections > C/C++ > General > and disable "Clang-Tidy", there are also other things which bothered me, such as variable spell-checking, which can also be disabled under the inspections menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can find on [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#disable-inspections) from jetbrains.com some explanations on how to disable inspections.

One of these method is temporary : Use the widget in the top-right corner of the editor and select the level 'None' in the Highlight list.